# How to print <li> 10 times under a div?

Tags: php, wordpress, html

I am making a website in wordpress and I have a div called `<div class="column dt-sc-one-half">` and under that i have a ul called `<ul class="menu-card check">` and under this `<ul>` i'm printing `<li>` 10 times through while loop. But I have total 50 `<li>` and I want to print only 10 `<li>` under this `<div>`  and next 10 under next div and so on.

For that I have written a code, but don't know why it isn't happening

```
<?php query_posts('page_id=5'); ?>
<?php while(have_posts()) : the_post();?>
<?php
if( have_rows('price_chart') ): while ( have_rows('price_chart') ) : 
the_row();
if( get_row_layout() == 'price_chart' ):?>

<?php
$i=0; ?>
<div class="column dt-sc-one-half">
<ul class="menu-card check">
<?php
while($i<10)
{
?>

<li><?php echo get_sub_field('item'); ?><span><?php echo 
get_sub_field('price'); ?></span></li>


<?php
++$i;
}
?>

</ul>
</div>



<?php endif;endwhile;endif;endwhile; ?>
```

Which Means I want a structure like this

```
                                <div class="column dt-sc-one-half">
                                <ul class="menu-card check">
                                    <li>Women's haircut<span>$75</span></li>
                                    <li>Shampoo And Style<span>$55</span></li>
                                    <li>Blow Dry Style<span>$49</span></li>
                                    <li>Thermal Press Style<span>$51</span></li>
                                    <li>Dandruff Rinse<span>$25</span></li>
                                    <li>Hair Coloring<span>$30</span></li>
                                    <li>Hair Color Removal<span>$35</span></li>
                                    <li>Hair And Scalp<span>$19</span></li>
                                    <li>Lash And Brow Tint<span>$38</span></li>
                                    <li>Cap Frosting<span>$25</span></li>
                                </ul>
                            </div>
                            <div class="column dt-sc-one-half">
                                <ul class="menu-card check">
                                    <li>Women's haircut<span>$75</span></li>
                                    <li>Shampoo And Style<span>$55</span></li>
                                    <li>Blow Dry Style<span>$49</span></li>
                                    <li>Thermal Press Style<span>$51</span></li>
                                    <li>Dandruff Rinse<span>$25</span></li>
                                    <li>Hair Coloring<span>$30</span></li>
                                    <li>Hair Color Removal<span>$35</span></li>
                                    <li>Hair And Scalp<span>$19</span></li>
                                    <li>Lash And Brow Tint<span>$38</span></li>
                                    <li>Cap Frosting<span>$25</span></li>
                                </ul>
                            </div>
```

But I am Getting this kind of structure

```
<div class="column dt-sc-one-half">
                                <ul class="menu-card check">
                                    <li>Women's haircut<span>$75</span></li>
                                    <li>Women's haircut<span>$75</span></li>
                                    <li>Women's haircut<span>$75</span></li>
                                    <li>Women's haircut<span>$75</span></li>
                                    <li>Women's haircut<span>$75</span></li>
                                    <li>Women's haircut<span>$75</span></li>
                                    <li>Women's haircut<span>$75</span></li>
                                    <li>Women's haircut<span>$75</span></li>
                                    <li>Women's haircut<span>$75</span></li>
                                    <li>Women's haircut<span>$75</span></li>
                                </ul>
                            </div>
                            <div class="column dt-sc-one-half">
                                <ul class="menu-card check">
                                    <li>Shampoo And Style<span>$55</span></li>
                                    <li>Shampoo And Style<span>$55</span></li>
                                    <li>Shampoo And Style<span>$55</span></li>
                                    <li>Shampoo And Style<span>$55</span></li>
                                    <li>Shampoo And Style<span>$55</span></li>
                                    <li>Shampoo And Style<span>$55</span></li>
                                    <li>Shampoo And Style<span>$55</span></li>
                                    <li>Shampoo And Style<span>$55</span></li>
                                    <li>Shampoo And Style<span>$55</span></li>
                                    <li>Shampoo And Style<span>$55</span></li>
                                </ul>
                            </div>
```

Comment: **For that I have written a code, but don't know why it isn't happening** Please specify what's happening with your code?

Comment: $i++;  missing dolour symbol

Comment: @MayankPandeyz i want 10 `<li>` under one div and ul and next ten `<li>` under next div and  ul

Comment: @JYoThI did it but getting ( syntax error, unexpected 'endwhile' ) this

Comment: your iterating same li 10 times @DipankarDas

Answer (score 3):

You have extra `endwhile` remove this. No need to add this.

PHP have two types of syntax

```
<?php
/* example 1 */

$i = 1;
while ($i <= 10) {
    echo $i++;  /* the printed value would be
                   $i before the increment
                   (post-increment) */
}

/* example 2 */

$i = 1;
while ($i <= 10):
    echo $i;
    $i++;
endwhile;
?>
```

You mixed both.

Comment: Ya it's working now. But my problem isn't solved yet....

But instead of coming different <li> 10 times its coming like same <li> 10 times

Comment: @DipankarDas : what does `get_sub_field` do ? Check this function and its returned value.

Answer (score 2):

$i is not increment properly in your code

```
<?php
++$i;

}
?>
```

Comment: syntax error, unexpected 'endwhile'  getting this error after putting ++$i;

Comment: remove endwhile